# Replace JSON fields with Scala Circe

Tags: scala, circe

Is there a proper way of changing all the values of the fields with a given key using [Scala Circe](https://circe.github.io)?

#### The scenario

I have n fields named `validTo` as dates (e.g. `"2024-09-12T00:00:00.000+00:00"`) and I need to shift those dates by a given number of days, so I need a way to find and replace all those `validTo` fields in that JSON.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I don't know the JsonPath of those fields in advance, but only their key (name).

I see that there is a function, inspired by Play framework, to find all the values of a given key in Circe: `io.circe.Json#findAllByKey`:

```scala
  /**
   * Recursively return all values matching the specified `key`.
   *
   * The Play docs, from which this method was inspired, reads:
   *   "Lookup for fieldName in the current object and all descendants."
   */
  final def findAllByKey(key: String): List[Json]
```

Comment: This needs to be applied recursively, not just to the top level?

Comment: It has to be done recursively, not just to the top level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use something like this:

```scala
//> using dep io.circe::circe-parser::0.14.6
//> using dep org.typelevel::cats-core::2.10.0

import scala.util.*
import io.circe.*, io.circe.parser.*
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val rawJson: String = """
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "validTo": "2020-10-11",
  "list of stuff": {
    "validTo": "2020-10-10",
    "pippo": 2
  }
}
"""

val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE

def parseDate(s: String): String = Try(LocalDate.parse(s, formatter)) match
  case Success(date) => formatter.format(date.plusDays(10))
  case Failure(_)    => s

def alter(json: Json): Json = json
  .mapArray(_.map(alter))
  .mapObject(obj =>
    JsonObject.fromIterable(obj.toList.map {
      case ("validTo", x) => ("validTo", x.mapString(parseDate))
      case (x, j)         => (x, j.foldWith(this))
    })
  )

object circe extends App:
  val json = parse(rawJson).getOrElse(Json.Null)
  println(alter(json).spaces2SortKeys)
```

where in the `parseDate` function you can handle as you want the date case, maybe even throwing exception

Alternatively, you can follow what @Daenyth said and use a `Folder[json]`:

```scala
val folder = new Json.Folder[Json] {
  def onNull: Json = Json.Null
  def onBoolean(value: Boolean): Json = Json.fromBoolean(value)
  def onNumber(value: JsonNumber): Json = Json.fromJsonNumber(value)
  def onString(value: String): Json = Json.fromString(value)
  def onArray(value: Vector[Json]): Json =
    Json.fromValues(value.map(_.foldWith(this)))
  def onObject(value: JsonObject): Json =
    Json.fromJsonObject(
      JsonObject.fromIterable(value.toList.map {
        case ("validTo", x) => ("validTo", x.mapString(parseDate))
        case (x, j)         => (x, alter(j))
      })
    )
  }

def alterFold(json:Json) = json.foldWith(folder)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do recursive transformations on circe json by using the [`fold`](https://circe.github.io/circe/api/io/circe/Json.html#fold%5BX%5D(jsonNull:=%3EX,jsonBoolean:Boolean=%3EX,jsonNumber:io.circe.JsonNumber=%3EX,jsonString:String=%3EX,jsonArray:Vector%5Bio.circe.Json%5D=%3EX,jsonObject:io.circe.JsonObject=%3EX):X) or [`foldWith`](https://circe.github.io/circe/api/io/circe/Json.html#foldWith%5BX%5D(folder:io.circe.Json.Folder%5BX%5D):X) methods

Pass a `Folder[Json]` (or the equivalent functions). For each type other than json objects, return your input as the relevant json type. For objects, transform their keys, probably using [`JsonObject#toMap`](https://circe.github.io/circe/api/io/circe/JsonObject.html#toMap:scala.collection.immutable.Map%5BString,io.circe.Json%5D)

Comment: Could you please provide a short example or point me to the right direction? Is there any documentation about this?

Comment: Only the javadoc unfortunately, but it's all very type-driven. It looks like Tonio added an example using Folder

Comment: We were discussing this approach on `#scala-italy` channel as well. Yes, Tonio's example is the missing piece. Now I can simply choose between two different implementation. Thank you for pointing out that we could also use `fold()`.